# Stuck partial wake lock in Android Vitals without WAKE_LOCK permission?

Tags: android

Our Android Vitals panel shows that we currently have 0.01% of Stuck partial wake locks (foreground). The problem is that we are not using `WAKE_LOCK` permission at all.

Some of the ideas why this could happen:

- We are using APK expansion library; However, we removed all PowerManager code from there;
- We are using MediaPlayer which could use PowerManager to keep the screen on. But once again, we don't have wake lock permission;
- We are keeping the screen on using `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

This happens mostly on devices with Android 8.0.0. Wake lock tag is "AudioMix". We checked merged manifest and final apk permissions.

We are using Android Studio, ndk 17b, target sdk 26, compile sdk 26. We are also using some ad providers like AdMob, Unity, etc.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Check your merged manifest. Perhaps 1+ libraries that you are using are adding and using the `WAKE_LOCK` permission.

Comment: I had the same issue, and did not have the WAKE_LOCK permission in the APK. I contacted Google and they confirmed it was a bug in the play store reporting. It was only showing up in Android 8.0 for me, and went away eventually (presumably they fixed it).

Comment: @TylerV I am having the same issue. Could you do me a big favor and get me the Google contact email you used and/or a link to the bug?

Comment: Same issue here. Hasn't found any solution.

Comment: @vargonian They didn't create a linkable issue for it, but the response I got was first "I’ve documented your issue and escalated it to our technical team for further investigation." then later "I'm happy to let you know you can disregard the vitals regarding wake locks, please note this is not pertaining to your app. This is a known issue and our technical team is working to resolve the issue." This was back in March 2018.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have a similar one.